# Geometric reasons finite fields have prime power orders?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, prime-numbers, field-theory, finite-fields

All variations of proofs that finite fields have prime power orders have a very algebraic feel to them. I was wondering - is there a more geometric way to see why this is true?

Comment: Finite fields are (after all) pretty algebraic kinds of things.  You might have a connection of finite fields with combinatorial designs (e.g. finite affine designs) that leads to some geometric insight, but it would expedite matters if you explained what geometric connection you are hoping for.

Comment: I have no geometric interpretation of what a prime number is (besides the idea of points in the topological space Spec, but it seems to me the word "geometry" in "algebraic geometry" is figurative rather than literal), so this doesn't sound very possible. Captain Lama's answer - that finite fields can be thought of as vector spaces in analogy with geometry and real numbers - sounds like the closest thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A finite field is a vector space over some $\mathbb{F}_p$, so it has a basis and its elements are in bijection with some $n$-uples of coordinates in $\mathbb{F}_p$, which tells you it has cardinal $p^n$. I don't know if you consider that a geometric or algebraic argument though.

Comment: How do you know each field is a vector space over some $\mathbb F_p$ without knowing the finite fields are $F_{p^n}$?

Comment: Any field must contain either $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some $p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ depending on its characteristic. Then for any fields $K$ and $L$, if $K\subset L$ then $L$ is a $K$-vector space in a natural way. In this case it will be of finite dimension because clearly a finite field must have a finite generating set (at worst, take all the elements).

Comment: @Arrow The fact that a finite field is a vector space over some $\mathbb{F}_p$ is *way* more basic and elementary than the classification of finite fields. One uses the former in proving the latter! Anyway, we know a finite field contains a subring generated by $1$, which must be $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n$ since the field is finite, and $n$ must be prime since there are no zero divisors, hence the finite field must contain $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ for some prime $p$, leading to it being a vector space over $\Bbb F_p$.

Answer (score 2):

If $k$ is a field (finite or not) you can associate to it  the one point scheme $X=\{x\}=\operatorname {Spec}(k)$.
Like all schemes  $X$  comes with a canonical morphism $can: X\to \operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb Z)$ whose image is the point $can(x)=z\in \operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb Z)$.
We then get the induced extension of residual fields $can^\ast :\kappa(z)\to \kappa (x)=k$ and since $k$ is finite so must be $\kappa (z)$,  which implies that $z=p\mathbb Z\in \operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb Z)$ for some prime $p$:
Indeed $\operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb Z) $ consists of the prime ideals $p\mathbb Z$  and of the ideal $0.\mathbb Z$, the generic point of  $\operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb Z)$, but $z_0= 0.\mathbb Z$ is excluded because  $\kappa(z_0)=\mathbb Q$ is infinite.
Thus $\kappa(z)=\mathbb F_p $ and from the set-finiteness of $k$  follows that the field extension $can^\ast: \kappa(z)=\mathbb F_p\to k$ makes of $k$ a finite-dimensional $\mathbb F_p$-vector space of cardinality $p^n$ for some positive $n$, just as required.

Needless to say all that can be said purely algebraically (and more simply!) but Grothendieck and his school have shown how such a  vision of field theory can lead to an astonishingly general theory, linking for example Galois theory and the topological theory of covering spaces.

Comment: Why does $k$ being a field imply so is $\kappa(z)$?

Comment: @Exterior : For any scheme $X$ and any point $z\in X$ the ring  $\kappa(z)=\mathcal O_{X,z}/\mathcal m_z$ is a field,  the residue field of the **local** ring $\mathcal O_{X,z}$.This has nothing to do with $k$.